# Import-Module SqlSp fails on TeamCity, works in native PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, teamcity, sqlps

I'm having an odd issue with running a PowerShell script as a TeamCity build step, particularly with `SqlPs` (though I'm not sure it's specific to `SqlPs`).

This one-line script fails in TeamCity:

```
Import-Module SqlPs
```

With the following error:

> ```
> Import-Module : The specified module 'SqlPs' was not loaded because no valid
> module file was found in any module directory.
> At C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\powershell2962302231054758126.ps1:13 
> char:1
> + Import-Module SqlPs
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>      + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (SqlPs:String) [Import-Module], 
>      FileNotFoundException
>
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands
>      .ImportModuleCommand
> ```

I'm pretty sure I have everything configured properly, because if I open PowerShell natively from the CI server that TeamCity is running on, I can run this with no problems.

I can even run the above temp script file that TeamCity generates from within the native PowerShell, and it works just fine.

Further, if I execute `Get-Module` from the native PowerShell:

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable
```

It will dump several system modules from:

> C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules

Along with the SqlSp modules from:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules

But when I run the same `Get-Module` from the TeamCity build, it will only list the system modules -- no `SqlSp` module.

I thought it might be an issue with permissions, but when I log in to native PowerShell as the same account that TeamCity uses, I still have no issues.

I also tried selecting x86 instead of x64 for bitness just to rule that out, and it fails either way.

Putting `"SqlPs"` in quotes also didn't help.

Comment: Just had the same issue and here the problem is that TeamCity starts the 32bit version of powershell, which doesn't have a ceratin module, whereas the 64bit version does have it. `Write-Host $env:PSModulePath` in a script to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't address the issue of why this doesn't work:

```
Import-Module SqlPs
```

I can get this to at least work by specifying the fully-qualified path in the `Import-Module`:

```
Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\SQLPS\SQLPS.PS1"
```

Would still love to find out why the first one isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Due to an issue unrelated to this issue, I ended up needing to upgrade TeamCity from version 8 to 9. Not sure why, but looks like `SqlSp` now works just fine under TeamCity 9.

Answer (score 0):

simple solution for your problem is add your module path to default module path see my example please
`$env:PSModulePath` this environment varibale for powershell module i want add another path to default psmodulepath 
first see default module path

```
C:\Users\soheil\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\Wind
owsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
```

now try to add another path to default path

```
$env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + ";c:\module\"
```

try again to see default path

```
C:\Users\soheil\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\Wind
owsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;c:\module\
```